# React подгрузить еще

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Здравствуйте, использую следующий код
`ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app-html'));`
Как чтоб вместо замены содержимого в блоке (app-html) оно дополнялось

Comment: статику держать в одном блоке, а рендером добавлять в следующий блок ниже по течению. С помощью стилей можно оформить так, что выглядить будет, как единое целое.

Answer (score 1):

***Вариант 1*** (вероятно не то, что вам нужно): в `'app-html'` находятся некие статичные данные, в `'app-content'` добавляются динамические.

```
<div id='app-html'>
    содержимое
    <div id='app-content'></div>
</div>
```

`ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app-content'));`

***Вариант 2***: реализовать компонент `<App />` таким образом, чтобы новое содержимое внутри него добавлялось к уже существующему.
Так как всё содержимое элемента `element` передаваемого методу `ReactDOM.render(<App />, element);` должно и будет очищаться и заменяться данными компонента `<App />`.